# DirectX Input Assembler Stage problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx-11

I am  recently started DirectX. My main source of learning is "3D game programming with DirectX 11" by Frank D. Luna. 
      In the Input Assembler stage, in the Rendering Pipeline, it has these lines of code:

```
ID3DX11Effect* mFX;
ID3DX11EffectTechnique* mTech;
/* ...create the effect... */
mTech = mFX->GetTechniqueByName("Tech");
D3DX11_PASS_DESC passDesc;
mTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);
HR(md3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(vertexDesc,
4,
passDesc. pIAInputSignature,
passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize,
&mInputLayout));
```

My code is this:

```
  // include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header files

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <xnamath.h>
#include <effects.h>




#define SCREEN_WIDTH  800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

// global declarations
IDXGISwapChain *swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device *dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context
ID3D11RenderTargetView *backbuffer;    // the pointer to our back buffer                                     
ID3D11VertexShader *pVS;    // the vertex shader
ID3D11PixelShader *pPS;     // the pixel shader

                                       // function prototypes
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void RenderFrame(void);     // renders a single frame
void CleanD3D(void);        // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void IA(void);
                            // the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = { 0, 0, 800, 600 };
    AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        L"WindowClass",
        L"Our First Direct3D Program",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        wr.right - wr.left,
        wr.bottom - wr.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    InitD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }

        RenderFrame();
    }


    // clean up DirectX and COM
    CleanD3D();


    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;                               // how many multisamples
    scd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;                             // multisample quality level
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;
    scd.BufferDesc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    scd.BufferDesc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

    // windowed/full-screen mode

    // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &swapchain,
        &dev,
        NULL,
        &devcon);


    // get the address of the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

    // use the back buffer address to create the render target
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    // set the render target as the back buffer
    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, NULL);


    // Set the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    viewport.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
}


// this is the function used to render a single frame
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f));

    // do 3D rendering on the back buffer here

    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    swapchain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);    // switch to windowed mode

                                                   // close and release all existing COM objects
    swapchain->Release();
    backbuffer->Release();
    dev->Release();
    devcon->Release();
    pVS->Release();
    pPS->Release();
}

//RENDERING PIPELINE//




//input layout//

void IA()
{

    struct Vertex
    {
        XMFLOAT3 Pos; //0 bit
        XMFLOAT3 Normal; // 12 bit
        XMFLOAT3 tex0; // 24 bit
        XMFLOAT3 tex1; // 32 bit
    };


    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC VertexDesc[] = {
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 24, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 1, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 32, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    };


    ID3D10Effect * mFX;
    ID3D10EffectTechnique * mTech;
    ID3D11InputLayout* mInputLayout;
    D3D10_PASS_DESC passDesc;


    mTech = mFX->GetTechniqueByName("Tech");
    mTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);

    dev->CreateInputLayout(
        VertexDesc,
        4,
        passDesc.pIAInputSignature,
        passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize,
        &mInputLayout);

    //Set I.L to the device
    devcon->IAGetInputLayout(&mInputLayout);



}
```

After compiling a get the error:

> C4700 uninitialized local variable 'mFX' used

But also these errors that I already had I think:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Warning   C4005   'D3D10_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\d3d10.h   609
>   Warning   C4005   'D3D10_ERROR_TOO_MANY_UNIQUE_STATE_OBJECTS': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\d3d10.h   608
>   Warning   C4005   'D3D11_ERROR_DEFERRED_CONTEXT_MAP_WITHOUT_INITIAL_DISCARD':
>   macro redefinition    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft
>   directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3d11.h   920
>   Warning   C4005   'D3D11_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\d3d11.h   918
>   Warning   C4005   'D3D11_ERROR_TOO_MANY_UNIQUE_STATE_OBJECTS': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\d3d11.h   917
>   Warning   C4005   'D3D11_ERROR_TOO_MANY_UNIQUE_VIEW_OBJECTS': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\d3d11.h   919
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    26
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    25
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    27
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_DRIVER_INTERNAL_ERROR': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    31
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_FRAME_STATISTICS_DISJOINT': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    29
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_GRAPHICS_VIDPN_SOURCE_IN_USE': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    30
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    21
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_MORE_DATA': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    23
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_NONEXCLUSIVE': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    32
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_NOT_CURRENTLY_AVAILABLE': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    33
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    22
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_REMOTE_CLIENT_DISCONNECTED': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    34
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_REMOTE_OUTOFMEMORY': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    35
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    24
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_ERROR_WAS_STILL_DRAWING': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    28 Warning  C4005   'DXGI_STATUS_CLIPPED':
>   macro redefinition    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft
>   directx sdk (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    13
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_STATUS_GRAPHICS_VIDPN_SOURCE_IN_USE': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    16
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_STATUS_MODE_CHANGED': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    17
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_STATUS_MODE_CHANGE_IN_PROGRESS': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    18
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_STATUS_NO_DESKTOP_ACCESS': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    15
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_STATUS_NO_REDIRECTION': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    14
>   Warning   C4005   'DXGI_STATUS_OCCLUDED': macro
>   redefinition  DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\dxgitype.h    12 Warning  C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2662 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2663 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2664 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2665 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2666 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2667 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2668 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2689 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2690 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2691 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2694 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2695 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2698 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2702 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2712 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2713 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2715 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2716 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2717 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2727 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2728 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2729 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2730 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2731 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2732 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2742 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2743 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamath.h 2754 Warning    C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathconvert.inl    2254 Warning    C4838   conversion
>   from 'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathconvert.inl    4523 Warning    C4838   conversion
>   from 'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathconvert.inl    4577 Warning    C4838   conversion
>   from 'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathconvert.inl    4639 Warning    C4838   conversion
>   from 'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathconvert.inl    4707 Warning    C4838   conversion
>   from 'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathconvert.inl    4770 Warning    C4838   conversion
>   from 'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathconvert.inl    4832 Warning    C4838   conversion
>   from 'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathmisc.inl   518 Warning C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathmisc.inl   519 Warning C4838   conversion from
>   'unsigned int' to 'INT' requires a narrowing
>   conversion    DX11proj    c:\users\spyros\documents\microsoft directx sdk
>   (june 2010)\include\xnamathvector.inl 1269

I am using Visual Studio 2015

Thanks in advance for all this bunch of code you read. I probably shouldn't have put all of it in one file.

Comment: Your `mTech = mFX->GetTechniqueByName("Tech");` function fails because `mFX` is not initialized. You should use `CreateFromFile` (or something similar) prior the `GetTechniqueByName` call. If that's fixed you can check the other errors.

Answer (score 1):

You must first create an effect by calling function.

```
D3D10CreateEffectFromMemory(<paste_here_your_effect_data_buffer>, <paste_here_your_effect_data_buffer_length>,
        0, <device_interface>, <effect_pool>, &mFX);
```

Where effect data you can read from effect file.

reading data process

```
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("effect.fx", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

    char* pcbBuffer = NULL;

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t nLength = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    pcbBuffer = new char[nLength];

    file.read(pcbBuffer, nLength);
    file.close();
```

where `pcbBuffer` will be our effect data, `nLength` our buffer length.

Comment: what exactly would be my effect data buffer length,device interface and effect pool?Thanks

Comment: @Frostice100: you could read effect file using `fstream` or native `CreateFile`. Read this file to the end in one big buffer. The length will be the length of file. Device interface is `ID3D10Device*`,  effect pool `ID3D10EffectPool`.

Comment: What is a effects pool exactly?And you say that it would be like this : D3D10CreateEffectFromMemory, fstream,
        0, dev,<effect_pool>, &mFX);   Thanks again for the help?

Comment: @Frostice100: No you fstream represents stream from wich you can read data not the data itself.

Comment: Also if I use this one will it be kay to continue?Thanks :)

Comment: So how it would be exactly?

Comment: @Frostice100: C++ standard library `#include <fstream>`